# InDesign: Section/Chapter Navigation Panel (extension workaround?)

Tags: adobe-indesign, software-recommendation, workflow

Can I **name chapters/sections** of pages in InDesign - as well as **navigate them** through a panel?
Yes, I've seen the *[a,b,c]-[i,ii,iii]-[1,2,3]*-solution suggested on this platform. I also know I can color-code and mark sections. In a document with +25 chapters of +50 pages, memorizing colors and numbers is not the most logical way to go. I'd assume I'm not the only one looking for a better workaround...

As it seems impossible within InDesign, is there perhaps an OS tool/extension to integrate?

*Example of Microsoft Word header and PowerPoint section navigation*
[image: Example of Microsoft Word and PowerPoint header navigation solutions]

Comment: Alas, no. A structural link-based overview like the _Navigation_ pane in Word is one of the things I truly miss in InDesign, but sadly there’s no such thing in InDesign. I’m not even aware of a plugin that mimics it, though I don’t think it would be a difficult plugin to make.

Comment: Thanks! It is what it is. Yes, I've been surprised to see the same question roaming internet forums for years (spotted one from 2012). Might get angry enough at some point to build my own plugin...